# AMCharts 5. Show tooltip only for truncated labels

Tags: amcharts5

Official AMCharts 5 documentation has a good example - https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/oNoXpVN. I want to do the same thing, but to show tooltip only for truncated labels.

I have tried to use adapters, but tooltip doesn't disappear on mouse leave.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? :(

```
const yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(
  am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: 'category',
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {}),
  })
);

const yRenderer = yAxis.get('renderer');

yRenderer.labels.template.setup = function (target) {
  target.set(
    'background',
    am5.Rectangle.new(root, {
      fill: am5.color(0x000000),
      fillOpacity: 0,
    })
  );
};

yRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
  centerX: am5.p0,
  tooltipText: '{category}',
  oversizedBehavior: 'truncate',
  maxWidth: MAX_Y_LABEL_WIDTH,
  tooltipY: 1,
});

yRenderer.labels.template.adapters.add('tooltip', (_, target) => {
  const width = target.width();

  return am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
    pointerOrientation: 'vertical',
    forceHidden: width !== MAX_Y_LABEL_WIDTH,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced the same issue. What worked for me was using *tooltipText* instead of *tooltip*.

```
yRenderer.labels.template.adapters.add('tooltipText', (label: string, target: am5xy.AxisLabel) => {
  if (!target?.width()) {
    return label;
  }

  return target.width() >= this.MAX_Y_LABEL_WIDTH ? '{category}' : '';
});
```